# Storing objects/ data set with increasing number of fields

Tags: java, database, nosql, persistence

In my application (a java based micro service) i want to persist some usage information. At the beginning i just want to store:

accessed object -> access count

The number of accessible objects is around 1 mio.
But the number of fields will increase and probably also contain complex data (embedded objects).
I am searching for a good approach or strategy to persist this data. I don't need a remote/distributed persistence layer. Local (where the service runs)/ embedded file based persistence would be sufficient.

My first idea is to store the data in an json or xml file. All fields will be optional. My only problem with this idea is the file size: the size would increase fast and loading/ updating the data could become a problem (I/O ?).

But what about (embedded) noSQL Databases? Is this an option, if yes what data bases should be considered?

Are there any other options?

Comment: You can use Json. Do you want to count Java objects in memory?

Comment: No i want to store usage data about accessed object.